# mysql find users how have achieved a title for 3 consecutive years

Tags: mysql

I have a table title where I store information about users who have achieved certain titles in certain years.

[The table structure of table "title"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y95d.png)

Now I need to find all users who have achived a cetain title for 3 consecutive years but couldn't figure out how. Example I want to show all users who have achieved the title "2" for 3 years 2014,2015,2016. here is what I tried:

```
SELECT t.id, t.staff_id, t.year, t.title_id 
FROM title AS t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT staff_id
    FROM title
    WHERE year IN (2014,2015,2016)
    GROUP BY staff_id 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) AS d
    ON d.staff_id = t.staff_id
WHERE title_id = 2
```

From the above sample data, I should expect to see staff_id 119 and 300. I however got other staff_id and older years like below:

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGJx1.png)

Someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is being caused by that although the subquery does return the `staff_id` values of those staff who were active in 2014, 2015, and 2016, it does not choose staff who had the title during these years.  I think you need to modify your subquery to the following:

```
SELECT staff_id
FROM title
WHERE year IN (2014, 2015, 2016) AND title_id = 2
GROUP BY staff_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

And I don't think you need the self join, because it no longer will add any new information.  You already know the `year` and `title_id` corresponding to the records in the result set.

Comment: that works without needing the self join. Thank you very much

Comment: just did. Thanks again